# Is it possible to remix cds / songs / audio within Reason 5? Can you open audio or anything like that?

Tags: reason

I would like to sample audio from popular songs to remix - is this possible within Reason 5 or Record 1.5?

Comment: Old question, but just to bring it up to date... [Reason 6](http://www.propellerheads.se/products/reason/) now includes a full suite of audio recording/editing tools.

Comment: Reason 6 did not make this possible. You still were not able to import or do much editing of audio files in a convenient way. They're adding this functionality in Reason 7 though. At least to a greater extent than in Reason 6.

Answer (score 5):

You can't do this is Reason. Reason is a synthesis engine and sampler with some MIDI tracking capabilities, but not a full-featured DAW.

You can do this in Record. Record is a full on DAW program, but with the Propellerhead Software take on how a DAW should be laid out.

Comment: Agree, Record actually has a build in "Sample" feature to record audio right into samplers like the Dr REX and NNXT.

Answer (score 1):

It certainly is possible in Record, but in Reason too, although dreadful. Nonetheless, I will explain the procedure in Reason: 
First you will have to export material you are working on into .wav/.aif clips. Then the clips have to be loaded into either Redrum or NN-XT. The actual remixing process is theoretically simple, simply trigger the audio clips in the playlist normally (and remix to your hearts will).

There are few advantages of doing this over other DAWs. Most of the time you will not be able to fast forward, because Reason doesn't directly support audio clips in playlist like other DAWs such as FL Studio or Cubase do. It simply triggers the sample once and plays it from start to finish (if not interrupted), and that's it. And because of the lack of support for audio clips in playlist you have little visual feedback about what you are doing. You can't simply see when a clip ends, you have to know it. But, if the audio clips you will be using are less than say, 5 seconds long, these might not be issues at all for you.

Record deals with all the disadvantages I've mentioned, and is a much saner DAW to use when using longer audio clips.

Answer (score 0):

Opening pre-rendered audio is a basic function of any modern day DAW.

I havn't used Reason 5 yet but I assume it will have this functionality. I know FL Studio does.

Comment: I haven't used Reason myself but I believe this isn't something it can do - Reason doesn't seem to be a DAW in the traditional sense so much as a virtual set of rack hardware.

Answer (score 0):

This was not possible in Reason 5 and was limited in Record. You can now do some of the stated things in Reason 7 but I'd avoid using Reason for this type of work. That's not what it was meant for and you'll be better off looking into other software for audio editing.